# Sentence making sense?

Tags: meaning-in-context, synonyms

I'm using a sentence that "Authors give this idea in that somehow describing attitude in another perspective" Here I want to use the sentences with the word contemplate (to view or consider)
"Authors give this idea in that somehow contemplating the attitude in another perspective"
Is this make sense I mean is it okay to use "contemplating" here? or any better option. Just to keep in view I'm asking from an academic writing perspective.

Comment: Are you trying to say: _Authors convey this idea by describing (or contemplating) attitude from a different perspective_? If this is the case, it would be good to tell us what _this idea_ and _attitude_ mean here. Essentially, you can contemplate something without describing it. But you cannot describe something without contemplating it.

Comment: @Shoe, Now I changed my sentence in another way around,  can you check this one"authors of the manuscript given this (I previously mentioned in my text) idea that describe ((or contemplate)) the energy internet from another perspective "

Comment: Sorry, but I don't feel able to give sensible feedback on a decontextualised sentence, whose meaning is not clear to me. As to your key question, I suggest you look up _describe_ and _contemplate_ in a good dictionary, and decide which is the better choice to convey your meaning.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but the idea of writing fancy for the 'academic writing perspective' may be the source of making your sentence hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say that you're asking from an academic perspective, do you mean that you're an academic? Or do mean that you only want answers from academics?

There are too many ways to interpret your sentence. For example:

- Authors contemplate this attitude from a different perspective.
- Authors have a different attitude when they contemplate this perspective.
- Authors have ideas that allow them to contemplate this attitude from different perspectives.

But to answer your question: Yes, I'm sure you can use the word *contemplate* when you rewrite the sentence.

Focus on clarity. Keep it simple.

Answer (score -1):

I take the sentence to mean the following;
Authors give or use this idea *in order to* somehow contemplate *or view* the attitude *from* another perspective

Your use of the phrase *in that* is out of place. It does not work here. Also the term *in another* is not normally used in this way. These provide blocks against getting your ideas across.

These prevent the sentence from making sense.